# PHP - making a switch statement using id from form input

Tags: php, forms, switch-statement

I'm making a short quiz in PHP that tells you what creature your thinking of based on 4 yes/no questions. I have made it so that depending on your answer to each question you get taken to a different question, I did this using mainly switch statements.

My question is is there any way that I can make a switch statement with the condition as the id from the submit buttons from the form?

```
      echo "<form method ='post' action='Creatures.php'>
     <input type='submit' name='answer' id='1' value='Yes' />
     <input type='submit' name='answer' id='2' value='No' />
     </form>";
```

This is the form I'm using to display the buttons, I have made it so that each button has a different id so at the end of the quiz, depending on what the id of the last button pressed is, I can display the right answer. Below is what I tried to do but it didn't work.

```
switch($_POST['id'])
{
 case 1: echo "It's a goldfish";
 case 2: echo "It's a eel";
}
```

Also these fields are the only ones which use id's throughout the whole web page, any suggestions on how I can get this to work properly, not necessarily using switch statements?

Comment: the name in $_POST corresponds to `name` attribute of the input, so it would be $_POST['answer'] and case 'Yes', 'No'

Comment: Thanks that is working, I was trying to use the id as I have 16 possible answers that I want to choose from, but half of them are called yes and half no (from when the user pressed the button in the quiz) so I would have to write 8 switch statements, there must be a better way than this.

Comment: then use the number as the value:  `<input type='submit' name='answer' id='2' value='2' />`

Comment: That changes the label of the submit button, though. Instead add a hidden input with the value of the id of the question, `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">` Then you have `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['answer']`

Comment: Thank You! This is working fine now, was not aware of the input type=hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
switch($_POST['answer']) {

case 'Yes':
   // do soemthing
   break;
case 'No':
   // do something
   break;
}
```

Comment: I have done everything you said and have added a hidden input field, so it is now working, yaayyy!

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors to this. Please study the following:

```
echo '<form method ="post" action="Creatures.php">
<button name="answer" type="submit" value="Yes">Yes</button>
<button name="answer" type="submit" value="No">No</button>
</form>';

switch($_POST['answer'])
{
   case 'Yes':
        echo "It's a goldfish";
        break;
   case 'No':
        echo "It's a eel";
        break;
}
```

Also see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp) and [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
break;
```

after each statement and your form input is wrong (`answer` instead of `id`). The NAME attribute is what determines the key in the POST array (the ID is for client side css and javascript only).

And as tigrang has pointed out, the value is what is being posted, not the ID, so the array would look like:

$_POST['answer']='Yes'

So your statement would be

```
switch($_POST['answer'])
{
 case 'Yes': echo "It's a goldfish";break;
 case 'No': echo "It's a eel";break;
}
```

Comment: and switch 'Yes' and 'No' - see my comment

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. when the browser sends the data from your form to the server in the form of key-value pairs. The keys are your form names, and the values are the values of the inputs.

so to get the value of your input name answer, you use `$_GET['answer'];`

which will either give you "Yes" or "No", because those are the values. You should also do some error checking since people can send arbitrary data to your servers, for example someone could visit `yoursite.com/creatures.php?answer=somerandomstuffthatidontexpect`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do it with jQuery/js, you will struggle. Various browsers will interpret this differently (own experience), so just go jQuery way :)

http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/ie6-and-multiple-button-submit-elements/ - this should help

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method ='post' name="formAnswer1" action=''>
    <input type='submit' name='answer' value='Yes' />
</form>

<form method ='post' name="formAnswer2" action=''>
    <input type='submit' name='answer' value='No' />
</form>

<?php
switch($_POST['answer'])
{
   case 'Yes': echo "Yes";
   break;

   case 'No': echo "No";
   break;
}
?>
```

Comment: as you have same name='answer' they can not be of 2 at the same time unless you define them as array like name='answer[]'

Comment: But only 1 is ever being posted. They are submit buttons.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
switch(key($_POST['answer']))
{
case 1: 
    echo "answer 1"; break;
case 2: 
    echo "answer 2"; break;
}
echo "<form method ='post' action='/tmp/test.php'>
<input type='submit' name='answer[1]' value='Yes' />
<input type='submit' name='answer[2]' value='No' />
</form>";
```

I think it works the way you want it to. But your approach is a bit counter-intuitive from programmers POV; consider using radiobuttons + submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use $_GET with a switch statement for my own class revision. This is what worked for me. The idea was to display something based on the grades entered on the form.

```
 <form action="processGrade.php" method "get">
 Enter your grade: <input type = "text" name ="grade">
 <input type = "submit">
 </form>
```

//On my processGrade.php form:

```
<?php
echo "You have entered: ".$mygrade = $_GET['grade'].". ";

switch($mygrade){

case 100:
    echo " Your grade is A";
    break;

case 70:
    echo " Your grade is B+";
    break;

default: echo "Ungraded";
}
?>
```